# How are Ports Exposed to the Network?

Tags: transport-protocol

When you register some server's port, whether it be an application, web, or something else - where exactly is this port registered?

I understand how ports work in that they are essentially signposts to applications once the packet has reached an IP address (for both sender and receiver).

What I haven't come across as of yet is where these signposts sit. My assumption is that the OS has a lookup table for up to 65535 distinct ports and when a server is set up, the software tells the operating system - "hey, send my packets to signpost 250". My reasoning for this is that as there's a [list of reserved ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), the OS must keep track of these somehow and any non-reserved ports are added to this table when registered by a server.

Is this assumption correct? Where does handling of an incoming packet's destination port and the receiving of the packet on the server occur?

Comment: Ports are addresses for _some_ transport protocols (others use nothing or something else), but each transport protocol that uses ports has a different set of ports, even if they use the same port numbers. TCP port 12345 is _not_ UDP port 12345.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the OS contains data structure(s) associating protocol address:ports to sockets used by programs.  When a program issues the `bind()`, `connect()`, or certain other system calls, the OS makes what can be simplified as a table entry.

This happens for listening ports (like a web server) and also for ports used by outgoing connections.

Your OS probably allows you to list the ports currently in use on your system.  On unix-like systems (including macOS) the command is `netstat`, for example:

```
jsw@boomer ~ % netstat -n
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  172.19.87.187.60920    18.234.32.175.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  172.19.87.187.60919    54.211.89.16.443       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  172.19.87.187.60918    172.217.7.133.443      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  172.19.87.187.60917    172.217.7.133.443      ESTABLISHED
```

Software can listen on `tcp 0.0.0.0:80` to receive any connection arriving on port 80.  Alternately, it can listen on a specific IP address, for example, `192.0.2.1:80` so it wouldn't receive connections to other IPs on the system.

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or other systems-focused sections of Stack Exchange might be a better resource for more in-depth information about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about transport-layer (L4) protocols like TCP and UDP that use ports for host subaddressing.

These ports are a property of their respective L4 protocol which is usually part of the network "stack", in turn part of the operating system.

The different layers and protocols are modular, so the actual table for TCP ports is located within the TCP protocol implementation ("handler"). Likewise, UDP ports are managed by the UDP protocol handler. All of those handlers and their underlying network-layer (L3) protocol (most prominently IPv4 and IPv6) form a "stack".

When an Ethernet frame is received by a network interface, its Ethertype is checked for which L3 protocol the payload belongs to - IPv4, IPv6, IPX, ... and the payload is passed to the appropriate protocol handler. That handler checks for the transport-layer protocol, indicated by the *Protocol* field for IP, and passes the payload on. That L4 protocol then checks for the port number and passes its payload on to the owning process.

(I'm simplifying, the reality is a bit more complicated and of course, there are alternatives to Ethernet and TCP/IP that may do things a bit differently.)